# Finding The Order Of A Group Upper Triangle Matrix

Tags: group-theory

> let $$H=\big{\{}\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & a & b \\
> 0 & 1 & c \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 
> \end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_3\big{\}}$$
>
> Find the order of $H$

First $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a group with addition so looking at

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a & b \\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2a & 2b+ac \\
0 & 1 & 2c \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

we get two operations we look at them as the same? meaning addition?

Comment: How many choices for $a$ are there? For $b$? For $c$? So how many total?

Comment: How many possibilities are there for $a,b,c$?

Comment: @Fakemistake for each one as the order of the group $3$ but how can I be sure there are no repetition?

Comment: Unless explicitly told otherwise, any group of square matrices has matrix multiplication as the operation.  Of course, the example you've given isn't matrix multiplication nor is it matrix addition, so I'm not following you.

Comment: @EricTowers even if the scalars are in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which the operation must be addtion?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field with both addition and multiplication.

Comment: @EricTowers yes but it is not a group with multiplication

Comment: $H$ is a group under multiplication.  I iterate : you haven't demonstrated addition or multiplication in your question, so I cannot follow what you believe you are presenting.

Comment: I think Eric is trying to point out that you've computed the example product incorrectly.

Comment: Ahh sorry I have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ choices you can make in this matrix, $a,b,c$. By the multiplicative rule for counting, this leaves you with $3^3$ different matrices.

This is good, because this is the Heisenberg group mod $3$, one of the 2 non abelian groups of order $3^3$.

Comment: How can I be sure that $a^2\neq c^3$ for example? and then I need to remove this count from the counting

Comment: Two matrices are the same iff their entries are the same.

Comment: @gbox I'm not quite sure what sure what you're stuck on. Remember also that the order of a group is the number of elements in the group.

Comment: @JoshB. I am thinking on a case let say in $Z_5*$ where $4^2=3 (\mod 5)$ so if this is the case we may have counted more options then there are

Comment: It may be helpful to just write down as many elements as you can, i.e. take $a=1,x,x^2$ where $x$ is the generator. Now for each of these options, $b=1,x,x^2$ and $c$ the same. This should convince you

Comment: The elements that we are counting are just 0 1 or 2 in each entry, we don't have to worry about multiplying them.

Comment: Thanks I got it!